# trying to run a CURL script in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, curl

I'm trying to run a CURL script in wordpress but I'm having a problem.

When i test it, i get a 500 internal error as WP changes the URL.

So the script is at www.site.com/curl_script.php - When i test that (navigate to www.site.com/curl_script.php) I end up going to www.site.com/curl_script.php/wp-admin/install.php which returns a 500 internal error.

Now after playing around with the script, I've noticed the problem. It seems to be a function that I'm running (the curl function) thats causing wordpress to take me to that url.

Ive had similar issues to this but have managed to fix it by simply changing the names of the functions, but this doesn't seem to work anymore.

**The function:**

```
  function verify_user($ref, $username, $uu_name){






    $ch = curl_init($server_root);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://site.com/con1.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $data = json_decode($result);

    global $ref_;

    $ref_ = $data->ref_id;


//fetch some more info

    $chh = curl_init($server_root);
    curl_setopt($chh,CURLOPT_URL,"http://site.com/con2.php");

    curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $resultt_2 = curl_exec($chh);

    $data_custt = json_decode($resultt_2);



    $cust_st = $data__->user_status;

    if ($cust_st == "FAILED"){

    echo "this is bad";


    }

    elseif ($cust_st == "PASSED") {

    echo "this is good";

    }
    }
    }
```

Now when i call this function:

```
verify_user_info($ref, $username, $uu_name);
```

Wordpress plays up...

But when i leave the function out (don't call it), everything works fine.

It seems that WP is assuming the user is attempting to run the installation, when that's not the case.

Any ideas on how to fix this, dynamically as others will use this script too?

Answer (score 0):

If sounds like you are getting redirected somehow, even though should shouldn't be if CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is not set. Try using the curl_getinfo function to debug the URL that is being accessed.